# Wordpress ACF repeater field loop

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to loop out a repeater field in my wordpress front-page template
But for some reason the div is empty and doesn't seem to work.
I am 100% sure my code is correct so there must be an issue.
Anyone has any idea what it could be?

This is how my loop looks like, the field keys are correct! :)

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Front Page Template
 */
?>

<?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> 
    <?php if( have_rows('achtergrond_afbeeldingen') ): ?>
        <div class="slider-circles">
                <?php while ( have_rows('achtergrond_afbeeldingen') ) : the_row(); ?>
                    <p id="slide1" data-bgimage="<?php the_sub_field('image'); ?>" class="transparent-circle slick-active"></p>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

This is what my front-page.php looks like. The funny thing I've used this in an other project before and everything worked fine. Now my screen is just blank, I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: Yes,the code is correct. http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/

Comment: What could be the reason then that the loop doesn't work? I check my source code and the div is empty

Answer (score 0):

if have_rows('field_56e7d8bebb545') is really true, debug the_row();

```
var_dump(the_row());
```

You can view the_result, if is empty, maybe you must set a second parameter for have_row($field_name, **$post_id**)

Comment: I am fairly new to WordPress, what is the $post_id exactly?

Comment: This is current page / post ID, You can try without this param, but you ca add global query `<?php if (have_posts()): ?>
 <?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> // you front page code
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif ?>`

Comment: If I do this my entire page is blank, unfortunately

Comment: Are You using a template for front page ?

Comment: Yes I do. I started from the sage wordpress template

Comment: ok, please checking you repeater field related with home page template

Comment: It's linked correctly, I use other fields and works fine. Only images doesn't seem to be loading.

Comment: Please try to change field name like a **gallery_images** and var dump `have_rows('gallery_images')`

Comment: It's not a gallary field it's a repeater field

Comment: ok ,try with rename to repeater field and `var_dump(have_rows('repeater field_name'))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106352/discussion-between-frank-lucas-and-htmlbrewery).

Comment: can you check out the chat, please?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one .. since you have not printed any such thing that can be displayed in browser .. you only provided the data attribute to div.

Write something inside inner HTML might see you repeater values

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Front Page Template
 */
?>

<?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> 
    <?php if( have_rows('achtergrond_afbeeldingen') ): ?>
        <div class="slider-circles">
                <?php while ( have_rows('achtergrond_afbeeldingen') ) : the_row(); ?>
                    <p id="slide1" data-bgimage="<?php the_sub_field('image'); ?>" class="transparent-circle slick-active"><?php the_sub_field('image'); ?></p>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: How do I inject the data into my html then?

Comment: you are getting the data in $rows ? then print it out and try to traverse that array or object

Comment: is it not working yet ? Since the repeater comes in paid version so I can't check here

Comment: A moment . I am checking

Comment: If this is the problem then you will die laughing .. check your inspect element.. you will see HTML populated correctly.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? There's noting if I check the source code

Comment: see the edited answer, same code is working for me . I just changed the field name

Comment: your answer does nothing, unfortunately. And via jQuery I use the data attribute to display a background image

Comment: then there is no problem in this code .. try this <?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); echo get_the_ID(); endwhile;?> , so that you can be sure that your post is fetched.

Comment: This also does nothing :/

Comment: check you functions.php it should not have any blank spaces at top and bottom . Means no space before "<?php" and no space after "?>"

Comment: Nope, doesn't have any blank spaces

Comment: then problem is something other buddy. Try to fetch  the repeater field by passing ID , as I suggested earlier

Comment: I don't understand, I did exactly the same in a previous project and everything worked fine. I see absolutely no reason why it wouldn't work now :/

Comment: there are 2 reasons I think , first check whether you have user pre_get_posts of parse_query  (i dont remeber the actual name ) OR 2nd can be some wp_query in functions.php might be missing wp_reset_postdata()

Comment: Sorry friend but I have a hard time understanding what you're trying to say

Answer (score 0):

`field_56e7d8bebb545` is the field key, not the field name. The field name must be used in the have_rows() function. This can be found on the Advanced Custom Fields screen next to the label -

[image]

Comment: I've tried that aswel doesn't work either. I've used the field key in previous projects and worked fine

Comment: If you're using a front-page.php template, the `while(have_posts()) : the_post();` loop is checking for content on the static front page. If there is no content there it would make send that nothing would be displayed. Your repeater loop doesn't need to be inside this other loop.

Comment: even if I remove that loop and only leave the repeater one it still doesn't work